# Batch processing GPX tracks

Tags: geoprocessing, import, qgis-modeler, gpx

I have a manual QGIS system that starts when I load a GPX file into QGIS and perform a number of actions on it. It all works perfectly.

I want to automate this process using the QGIS Graphical Modeler, so I can batch process a whole directory of GPX files.

When I start the process manually the GPX import dialogue box asks which vector layers I want to load from the GPX file:[image]

I select the tracks layer and everything proceeds smoothly.

To automate my system I use the Vector Layer Input element in the Graphical Modeler. I define the import as Line so that it can be picked up by Polygonize.

[image]

However, when I try to polygonize this line layer the process fails - I am not sure why - maybe because there are no routes defined in my GPX files?

**UPDATE: I swapped the `<trk>` and `<trkpt>` tags for `<rte>` and `<rtept>` tage in a GPX file and made a 'route layer'. Manually I was able to make a polygon from the route line but, once again, the automated model failed failed to make a polygon.**

Is there a way to get around this problem? I have tried many different things including GPS Tools, Batch GPS Importer, Merging layers, Fixing geometries. I have run out of ideas.

---

As requested by Erik:

Here is an example track:
[image]

I can polygonize the "loop" manually - but not with the Graphical Modeler:
[image]

The Graphical Model:
[image]

Sample GPX (of a shorter track) made with the same GPX tracker:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gpx xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd" version="1.1" creator="Open GPX Tracker for iOS">
    <trk>
        <trkseg>
            <trkpt lat="50.92371170879427" lon="0.7082069478935639">
                <ele>1.6512947082519531</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:12:17Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.923746284144855" lon="0.7085257116711777">
                <ele>17.26394271850586</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:12:18Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.9237622516704" lon="0.7084496039903802">
                <ele>36.04580307006836</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:12:20Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92375919227574" lon="0.7084884960210961">
                <ele>35.53786849975586</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:12:22Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.923756803433335" lon="0.7085274718708438">
                <ele>33.56557846069336</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:12:23Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92375382785771" lon="0.7085764221853657">
                <ele>33.50826644897461</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:12:24Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92374808625404" lon="0.7086478360003872">
                <ele>33.09322738647461</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:12:25Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.923741632188595" lon="0.7087280508137389">
                <ele>33.21499252319336</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:12:26Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.923732915009296" lon="0.7088175695396111">
                <ele>33.34707260131836</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:12:27Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92372294054452" lon="0.708912452683513">
                <ele>32.77730941772461</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:12:28Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.923710661056376" lon="0.7090169750160621">
                <ele>33.23983383178711</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:12:29Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92367763635788" lon="0.7091986946768213">
                <ele>33.10921859741211</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:12:30Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92366703325037" lon="0.7093041390187194">
                <ele>32.85805892944336</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:12:31Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92365525667641" lon="0.709406482056444">
                <ele>32.01839828491211</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:12:32Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.923644611659384" lon="0.7094848528510979">
                <ele>31.03518295288086</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:12:33Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92363086533818" lon="0.7095674145973376">
                <ele>30.08053207397461</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:12:34Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92362126805905" lon="0.7096602022654467">
                <ele>29.83437728881836</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:12:35Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.923615568364895" lon="0.7097575999803001">
                <ele>29.83669662475586</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:12:36Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.923605845357216" lon="0.7098427601165229">
                <ele>28.89907455444336</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:12:37Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92359729581598" lon="0.7099391520029957">
                <ele>28.59688949584961</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:12:38Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.923586525070405" lon="0.7100349571562465">
                <ele>27.77956771850586</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:12:39Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.923579442362225" lon="0.7101314328617511">
                <ele>27.08919906616211</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:12:40Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.923572862568236" lon="0.7102274056530653">
                <ele>26.73189926147461</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:12:41Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92356552840296" lon="0.7103212829685865">
                <ele>26.22274398803711</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:12:42Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92355702077124" lon="0.7104127295321881">
                <ele>25.90444564819336</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:12:43Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92354692057792" lon="0.7104945369071425">
                <ele>26.00008773803711</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:12:44Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92353874822233" lon="0.7105660345411957">
                <ele>25.42531967163086</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:12:45Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.923535227822995" lon="0.7106451597071352">
                <ele>25.17019271850586</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:12:46Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92353975405071" lon="0.7107050064957801">
                <ele>25.48318099975586</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:12:47Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.923565779860056" lon="0.7107523642486993">
                <ele>25.87997055053711</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:12:48Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.923597547273076" lon="0.7107781805104676">
                <ele>26.64352035522461</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:12:49Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92363723558459" lon="0.710800141096777">
                <ele>26.77114486694336</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:12:50Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92368559916589" lon="0.7108232751495306">
                <ele>26.55404281616211</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:12:51Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92373806987975" lon="0.7108435593552057">
                <ele>26.42371265063997</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:12:52Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.923790079588926" lon="0.7108614966279928">
                <ele>26.513888242322253</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:12:53Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.9238404967365" lon="0.7108793500817482">
                <ele>26.586919717786287</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:12:54Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92388940514151" lon="0.7109026517725651">
                <ele>26.712211571288506</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:12:55Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.923939528922475" lon="0.7109227683401768">
                <ele>26.646315398652504</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:12:56Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92398944315586" lon="0.7109460700309937">
                <ele>26.812293484046307</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:12:57Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.924041620503104" lon="0.7109681144363349">
                <ele>26.935579841771272</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:12:58Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.924096941064036" lon="0.7109971158213084">
                <ele>26.841609091149223</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:12:59Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92415268072013" lon="0.711021674797601">
                <ele>26.70317091815926</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:13:00Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.924199954654014" lon="0.7110448926693862">
                <ele>26.326055522758892</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:13:01Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92423033905301" lon="0.7110583875334925">
                <ele>26.234783411730035</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:13:02Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92426047199491" lon="0.7110602315521902">
                <ele>26.599450027210423</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:13:04Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.924281594390905" lon="0.711052939296431">
                <ele>26.626202238266302</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:13:11Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.9243085422096" lon="0.7110593095428414">
                <ele>26.705974181921235</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:13:12Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92434609313581" lon="0.7110718823975987">
                <ele>26.476546600781703</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:13:13Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92438896657053" lon="0.7110841199762291">
                <ele>26.389641832245104</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:13:14Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92443494130943" lon="0.7111029792583651">
                <ele>26.39299468498554</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:13:15Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.9244670859081" lon="0.7111246045685476">
                <ele>25.983006228342646</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:13:16Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92448661574249" lon="0.7111314777291483">
                <ele>25.776633927711288</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:13:17Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92450761240993" lon="0.7111342437571949">
                <ele>26.322726107985773</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:13:20Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.924539170275374" lon="0.7111429609364933">
                <ele>26.3746936109047</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:13:21Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92458472591911" lon="0.7111588865525192">
                <ele>26.311654116876127</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:13:22Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92463686135684" lon="0.7111830264336534">
                <ele>26.393013106595703</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:13:23Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.924699725630624" lon="0.7112086750573583">
                <ele>26.803824915226585</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:13:24Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92477088798855" lon="0.7112377602613635">
                <ele>27.228360667459697</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:13:25Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92484557074581" lon="0.7112668454653688">
                <ele>27.43562472881267</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:13:26Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92492469591175" lon="0.7112973555929133">
                <ele>27.43098550910068</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:13:27Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92500277333979" lon="0.711321579293079">
                <ele>27.49138827920848</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:13:28Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92507657599722" lon="0.7113477308309742">
                <ele>27.451959210587603</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:13:29Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.925148744183524" lon="0.7113661710179516">
                <ele>27.602713514843146</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:13:30Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92521760151808" lon="0.7113836891955801">
                <ele>27.470555512322647</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:13:31Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92527971142058" lon="0.7114070747054287">
                <ele>27.28972217239543</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:13:32Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92533654072408" lon="0.711419396103091">
                <ele>27.322261897605046</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:13:33Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92538347938184" lon="0.7114233355975816">
                <ele>27.41228642262091</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:13:34Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92542178467934" lon="0.7114251796162794">
                <ele>27.281445691244983</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:13:35Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.925448606769486" lon="0.7114093378192851">
                <ele>27.410578074520643</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:13:36Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92546595730905" lon="0.7113708648837277">
                <ele>27.494117849573428</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:13:37Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92547890734945" lon="0.7113188970840642">
                <ele>27.796823929969776</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:13:38Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92548879799519" lon="0.7112524285919137">
                <ele>27.8311520680854</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:13:39Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.925493743318064" lon="0.7111727166927524">
                <ele>28.091817772829202</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:13:40Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92549994592641" lon="0.7110786717391676">
                <ele>28.115254965504917</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:13:41Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92551582963292" lon="0.7109762448824113">
                <ele>28.404458949296526</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:13:42Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92552521736447" lon="0.7108576409525339">
                <ele>28.404458949296526</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:13:43Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92553569474344" lon="0.7107356842613879">
                <ele>28.765100453409175</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:13:44Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.925543196546776" lon="0.7106285635388555">
                <ele>29.02086428383049</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:13:45Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92555639804427" lon="0.7105218619114817">
                <ele>29.021046839134954</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:13:46Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.925570228184505" lon="0.7104164175695836">
                <ele>29.306733480633625</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:13:47Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92557928063993" lon="0.7103227078921257">
                <ele>29.366689521210844</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:13:48Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92558917128567" lon="0.7102509588009773">
                <ele>29.248758605981294</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:13:49Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92559566726063" lon="0.7101974822587428">
                <ele>29.323455952395108</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:13:50Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.925597134093685" lon="0.7101650442934689">
                <ele>29.275892498933956</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:13:51Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.925600989769144" lon="0.7101222965872941">
                <ele>29.5390771562233</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:13:53Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.925606438006206" lon="0.710090780631369">
                <ele>29.76854427084851</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:13:54Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92561188624327" lon="0.7100362144417223">
                <ele>30.087300664874476</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:13:55Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92561821458016" lon="0.7099637947983201">
                <ele>30.082460252814357</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:13:56Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92562709939752" lon="0.7098750304437335">
                <ele>30.08410891198342</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:13:57Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.925640133256955" lon="0.7097749505198652">
                <ele>30.30020222428348</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:13:58Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92565262229268" lon="0.7096758764243775">
                <ele>30.29191205534073</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:13:59Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92566628479485" lon="0.7095677498734645">
                <ele>30.48165290340839</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:14:00Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92567521152173" lon="0.7094554323709658">
                <ele>30.75058839918728</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:14:01Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92569130477582" lon="0.7093446236110379">
                <ele>31.003867646600924</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:14:02Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92570161451672" lon="0.709234401584332">
                <ele>31.185400645787922</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:14:03Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.925711756619556" lon="0.7091231737292456">
                <ele>31.163211255802523</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:14:04Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92571971942757" lon="0.709017897025411">
                <ele>31.0581810836147</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:14:05Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.925726131583495" lon="0.7089133746928619">
                <ele>31.221614812314073</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:14:06Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92573082544927" lon="0.7088148035115645">
                <ele>31.285306546649053</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:14:07Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.925736147957785" lon="0.7087381090975448">
                <ele>30.661844930116203</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:14:08Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92573983599518" lon="0.7086849678314372">
                <ele>30.504748044531183</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:14:09Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92574440413241" lon="0.7086551282561464">
                <ele>30.156179157525685</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:14:10Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92573744715278" lon="0.7086213491863651">
                <ele>34.83034896850586</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:14:12Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.9257171629471" lon="0.7085593231028957">
                <ele>33.22182846069336</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:14:14Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.925685144076986" lon="0.7085423916584891">
                <ele>33.23159408569336</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:14:15Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92564415657048" lon="0.7085309922701758">
                <ele>33.00887680053711</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:14:16Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92559139249001" lon="0.7085196767008942">
                <ele>32.80520248413086</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:14:17Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92554248408501" lon="0.7085091993219298">
                <ele>33.41360092163086</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:14:18Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92548578051005" lon="0.7084827963269394">
                <ele>33.48092269897461</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:14:19Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92541935392742" lon="0.7084625121212643">
                <ele>33.80752182006836</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:14:20Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.925348233479006" lon="0.7084397133446377">
                <ele>33.83517074584961</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:14:21Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92528260317717" lon="0.7084162440157573">
                <ele>33.77938461303711</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:14:22Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.925204274292035" lon="0.7083810400224368">
                <ele>34.43001937866211</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:14:23Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92513126791541" lon="0.7083602529025714">
                <ele>35.03786849975586</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:14:24Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.9250611952049" lon="0.7083409745252769">
                <ele>35.45528793334961</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:14:25Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92499845665966" lon="0.7083209417766969">
                <ele>35.97408676147461</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:14:26Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.924932826357825" lon="0.7083055190748612">
                <ele>36.54256820678711</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:14:27Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92488270257686" lon="0.708293784410421">
                <ele>36.89150619506836</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:14:28Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92484565456484" lon="0.7082810439176003">
                <ele>37.06985092163086</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:14:29Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92481807810341" lon="0.7082791160798708">
                <ele>36.89364242553711</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:14:30Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.924780066172524" lon="0.7082658726728598">
                <ele>37.16598129272461</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:14:32Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.924750100868685" lon="0.70826050825483">
                <ele>36.89645004272461</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:14:33Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.924709742004914" lon="0.7082420680678526">
                <ele>36.52462387084961</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:14:34Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.924652786972864" lon="0.7082252204424778">
                <ele>36.94649887084961</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:14:35Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92459122189407" lon="0.7082003261900583">
                <ele>37.16677474975586</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:14:36Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92453254857187" lon="0.7081769406802096">
                <ele>37.36825180053711</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:14:37Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.924468846107764" lon="0.7081636972731986">
                <ele>37.80276107788086</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:14:38Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.924402796710766" lon="0.7081545609987416">
                <ele>37.84731674194336</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:14:39Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.924334903295076" lon="0.708150034771029">
                <ele>38.59402084350586</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:14:40Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92425866988573" lon="0.7081266492611804">
                <ele>36.628197377484</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:14:41Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92418340039525" lon="0.7081135734922328">
                <ele>38.73598861694336</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:14:42Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92409568377856" lon="0.7080856617546716">
                <ele>38.46114730834961</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:14:43Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92402041428808" lon="0.7080589234835543">
                <ele>37.87435531616211</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:14:44Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92394598298792" lon="0.7080362923449911">
                <ele>37.57210922241211</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:14:45Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.923880646052694" lon="0.7080253120518364">
                <ele>37.73440170288086</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:14:46Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.923820757354534" lon="0.7080272398895658">
                <ele>37.27346420288086</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:14:47Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92378425416622" lon="0.7080532237893976">
                <ele>36.86080551147461</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:14:48Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.923749930272734" lon="0.7081028446561732">
                <ele>36.31332015991211</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:14:49Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92373723168943" lon="0.7081779465085902">
                <ele>36.37917709350586</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:14:50Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.923732328276074" lon="0.7082662917680184">
                <ele>36.24892807006836</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:14:51Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.923727676319814" lon="0.7083582412458103">
                <ele>36.28762435913086</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:14:52Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.923739494803286" lon="0.7084759231663388">
                <ele>36.51101303100586</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:14:53Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92373765078459" lon="0.70858396589822">
                <ele>36.99831771850586</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:14:54Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92372771822933" lon="0.7086977921432897">
                <ele>37.05367660522461</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:14:55Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.923713804270065" lon="0.7087969500578091">
                <ele>37.34432601928711</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:14:56Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92370634437624" lon="0.708906836808388">
                <ele>37.07345199584961</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:14:57Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.923700435134506" lon="0.7090118620551275">
                <ele>33.618792790869634</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:14:58Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92368874237958" lon="0.7091062422848391">
                <ele>33.216994895181244</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:14:59Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92367512178693" lon="0.7092047296471048">
                <ele>32.84795945060941</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:15:00Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92367005073551" lon="0.709284525365298">
                <ele>32.697421165695346</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:15:01Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.923659363808966" lon="0.7093410193926741">
                <ele>32.87653969279934</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:15:02Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.92365739406172" lon="0.7093771453953435">
                <ele>33.09877055580819</ele>
                <time>2020-05-16T15:15:08Z</time>
            </trkpt>
        </trkseg>
    </trk>
</gpx>
```

---

Data Log:
With QGIS Graphical Modeler:

```
Prepare algorithm: qgis:polygonize_1
Running Polygonize [1/6]
Input Parameters:
{ INPUT: '/Users/peqi/Downloads/GPX/16-May-2020-1531.gpx', KEEP_FIELDS: False, OUTPUT: 'memory:Polygons from lines' }
Processing lines…
Noding lines…
Polygonizing…
No polygons were created!
OK. Execution took 0.165 s (1 outputs).
```

Manually:

```
Processing algorithm…
Algorithm 'Polygonize' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'INPUT' : '/Users/peqi/Downloads/GPX/16-May-2020-1531.gpx|layername=tracks', 'KEEP_FIELDS' : False, 'OUTPUT' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT' }

Processing lines…
Noding lines…
Polygonizing…
Saving polygons…
Execution completed in 0.10 seconds
Results:
{'OUTPUT': 'Polygons_from_lines_44578c71_16a0_40b5_827e_a6ce3393bfe5'}

Loading resulting layers
Algorithm 'Polygonize' finished
```

---

Model script:
https://pastebin.com/m8uSnARj

---

Compare manual input:

```
'INPUT' : '/Users/peqi/Downloads/GPX/16-May-2020-1531.gpx|layername=tracks'
```

with the Model:

```
{ INPUT: '/Users/peqi/Downloads/GPX/16-May-2020-1615.gpx', KEEP_FIELDS: False, OUTPUT: 'memory:Polygons from lines' }
```

Is that missing '... |layername=tracks' the problem?

---

Comment: You are wondering why you can't create polygons from non-closed lines? Why are you trying to polygonize in the first place? What result do you expect?

Comment: They are closed lines.

Comment: The manual process works fine. I can't work out how to automate it with the Graphical Modeler.

Comment: Can you share example data and the model?

Comment: Here you are. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Works fine for my with the data you provided. Maybe one of the other tools throws an error. Do you get any error messages? Did you run the whole process manually? Can you actually provide your model for download?

Comment: I have added the Data Logs for the graphical modeler and the manual process.

Comment: Yes i can run the whole process manually. The only error i get is with Polygonize. (see data logs).

Comment: Added link to script: https://pastebin.com/m8uSnARj

Comment: I dealt with GPX just recently in Graphical modeller and struggled too. The problem is straight at the beginning when reading GPX as input. It simply does not load tracks at all. I think the problem is that it reads only 'first layer' from GPX called route_points. I asked the question on how to load tracks here - https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/374421/how-to-load-gpx-tracks-in-graphical-modeller-as-input

Answer (score 0):

The GPX file needs to be converted into a .shp file before it can be processed by the Graphical Modeler.

Load the .gpx file as a layer in QGIS, right click on the layer in the layer browser >> export >> save as >> ESRI Shapefile (give it a name and select a writable destination directory).

This cannot be done as a QGIS batch process (as far as I know)

This .shp file can be opened and processed by the graphical modeler.

Comment: No - it's the start of a whole new heap of (unnecessary) pain.

Comment: Isn't the answer enough?

Comment: It is a complete answer.

Comment: `.shx` is the offset information for a shapefile. No file geodata format could be converted into the fixed width feature offset file, so this makes no sense as a comment, much less as an answer.

Comment: With QGIS (open .gpx >> export as .shx) - but not with the Graphical Modeler.

Comment: Is your issues solved? I am the developer of Batch GPS Importer. Let me know if you still need help on this.