# How to load GPX tracks in graphical modeler as input

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler, gpx

Is there a way to load tracks from GPX into graphical modeler as vector input?

When you open GPX in QGIS, it comes up with dialog listing layers:

- route_points
- routes
- track_points
- tracks
- waypoints

It seems to me in graphical modeler only first layer route_points is getting loaded. So I guess in graphical modeler for vector input you need to specify you want to load 'tracks' and not other layers somehow?

Comment: - Did you ever find a way around this?

Comment: - In your model is the GPX file already loaded in the project? or did you manage to make a step in the graphical modeler to load the GPX layer from a file on your PC to use as input?    I am trying to do this but without success.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the track, the plugin "GPX Segment Importer" may help you.  It works in the Graphical Modeler.